# HTML - мне нужно перекрасить чередовано цвета строк таблицы

Tags: html

Мне нужно  чередовано перекрасить цвета строк таблицы  . Например первая яйчека белая , вторая синяя , третья белая , четвертая синяя , в таком порядке  !

Comment: Cм. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так

```css
.table-test-odd {
    width: 400px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px #e4e4e4 solid;
}

.table-test-odd tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #06f;
    color: #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-test-odd">
  <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>even - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td>odd - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>even - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>4.</td>
        <td>odd - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
         <td>5.</td>
         <td>even - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>6.</td>
        <td>odd - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>7.</td>
        <td>odd - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>8.</td>
        <td>odd - row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>9.</td>
        <td>even - row</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , просто не знал как сделать )